# When to use Observable.subscribeOn()

Tags: rx-java, reactivex

I'm new to ReactiveX/Rx-java. I can not yet understand when do I need to use `subscribeOn()`, and how should I choose which Scheduler to pass in.

Comment: What have you read so far about it?

Comment: There are quite a lot of blog posts about them: [subscribeOn](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-rxjava-subscribeon-and-observeon-744b0c6a41ea), [schedulers](http://www.baeldung.com/rxjava-schedulers), etc.